# Python returning function results

Tags: python, performance

What is better with respect to speed and code optimization? Performing a computation, storing the result reference locally and returning the reference like so:

```
def aplusb(a,b):
    result = a + b
    return result
```

or return whatever the computation returns directly to the caller:

```
def aplusb(a,b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: In theory you are performing some redundant extra operations in the first version. In practice there is no way it would ever make a difference to your program's speed, but the second version is clearer.

Comment: the speed cost is likely so nominal that you needn't ever worry about it in this case. With Python, you should usually go with the most readable option. Do "import this" in your Shell

Comment: `a + b` doesn't normally need its own function so I'm guessing your actual issue is not being demonstrated here.

Comment: In general, don't use temporary variables if you don't need to

Comment: The 1st one is marginally slower, but the speed difference is very tiny. OTOH, using a function merely to compute a single addition is much slower than doing the addition inline: Python function calls are relatively slow.

Comment: Don't think about such details beforehand. Write readable source and finally use a profiler to find out where and how to optimize the code.

Comment: OTOH, using well-named temporary values _can_ make the code more readable, but that doesn't really apply here, and in fact the temporary variable just makes the code more verbose without enhancing the meaning, so the 1st version is more readable because it's less cluttered. FWIW, if you ran those two functions trillions of times the time difference between them would probably be less than the time it took you to ask this question. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first executes two more bytecodes, one for storing the result, the other for retrieving it again:

```
>>> def aplusb_local(a, b):
...     result = a + b
...     return result
...
>>> def aplusb_return(a, b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(aplusb_local)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (result)

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                2 (result)
             10 RETURN_VALUE    
>>> dis.dis(aplusb_return)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

You also need a little more local variable space in the function frame object:

```
>>> aplusb_local.__code__.co_nlocals
3
>>> aplusb_return.__code__.co_nlocals
2
```

The differences here are **extremely marginal**; a 0.038 second difference on 10 million calls on my Macbook Pro:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('aplusb(42, 81)', 'from __main__ import aplusb_local as aplusb', number=10**7)
1.0834476329619065
>>> timeit('aplusb(42, 81)', 'from __main__ import aplusb_return as aplusb', number=10**7)
1.045598166063428
```

This is not something you should be optimising for.

Optimise for *readability* instead.